# Decimal formatting ticks on Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot but the ticks are like this: `0.200558, 0.202004`

[image: 0.200 0.202]

I wanted someting like: `0.200, 0.202, 0.204`

I tried

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.3f'))
```

but that's what I got: `0, 5.000, 10.000`

[image: 0 5 10]

Answer (score 1):

I usually find it easier to generate the ticks with `np.arange` and the set the correct formatting using `f-strings` and list comprehension. It's important to set the ticks first, and then set the tick labels.

See the example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate 10 random points between 0 and 1
data = np.random.random(10)

# Plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(10,8)
)
ax.plot(data)

# Generate and format the ticks
y_ticks = np.arange(0,1, 0.123)
ax.set_ylim(y_ticks[0], y_ticks[-1])
ax.set_yticks(y_ticks)
ax.set_yticklabels(
    [f"{label:.3f}" for label in y_ticks]
);
```

This is what you'll [get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zinik.png).